# Android Map problem in Emulator

Tags: android

I have a Google Map activity display problem. I have developed an Android application which uses the Google Map API and now application is working but only showing blank map. I got map key after providing MD5 certificate. I'm getting really very fed up. Not getting any solution.

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hello.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/mapsicon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />

        <activity android:name=".map" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0VLe45SDuqjxrUhIc1-HWVybCFmiqzeKiz9kk0g"
        />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Java file

```
package com.hello.map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;



public class map extends MapActivity
{
    MapView mapView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: Did you follow the hello maps tutorial and register your keystore with the google map api?

Comment: Thanks dear for reply.
yes i registered and got the Key.
but it is showing blank map. and instead of that one map ICOn is installed in emulator. and showing the correct map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct maps api key.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    **android:apiKey="************YOUR_KEY_HERE**********"
    />
```

see http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: I have obtained and set the key. I just didn't want to publish it online.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Why not? Then you can't publish your app (or at least not without a functional map).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the required permission in your Manifest:

- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- android.permission.INTERNET

Answer (score 0):

Are you working behind a proxy? i suggest to use a direct internet connection if you are. And yeah don't forget the INTERNET_PERMISSION in your AndroidManifest.xml